# How would I implement this maximumGrade function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream> // For file handling
#include <iomanip> // For formatted output
#include <iostream> // For cin, cout, and system
#include <string> // For string data type
#include "CourseGrade.h"
using namespace std;

CourseGrade* maximumGrade(CourseGrade* course0, CourseGrade* course1)
{

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Course Grade App!" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //Prompting and creating CourseGrade objects and pointer values from inputs
    int c1;
    float g1;
    cout << "Please enter the first course and its grade: ";
    cin >> c1 >> g1;
    CourseGrade Course0(c1, g1);
    CourseGrade* ptrCourse0;
    ptrCourse0 = &Course0;

    int c2;
    float g2;
    cout << "Please enter the second course and its grade: ";
    cin >> c2 >> g2;
    CourseGrade Course1(c2, g2);
    CourseGrade* ptrCourse1;
    ptrCourse1 = &Course1;

    int c3;
    float g3;
    cout << "Please enter the third course and its grade: ";
    cin >> c3 >> g3;
    CourseGrade Course2(c3, g3);
    CourseGrade* ptrCourse2;
    ptrCourse2 = &Course2;


    cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Course" << setw(10) << "Grade" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << ptrCourse0->getCourse() << setw(10) << ptrCourse0->getGrade() << endl;
    cout << ptrCourse1->getCourse() << setw(10) << ptrCourse1->getGrade() << endl;
    cout << ptrCourse2->getCourse() << setw(10) << ptrCourse2->getGrade() << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "The course with the maximum grade is: " << maximumGrade(ptrCourse0, ptrCourse1) << endl;

    cout << "The average grade is: " << (ptrCourse0->getGrade() + ptrCourse1->getGrade() + ptrCourse2->getGrade()) / 3 << endl;
}
// End of main.cpp

void CourseGrade::setCourse(int c)
{
    if (c >= 1000 && c <= 9999)
    {
        course = c;
    }
}

void CourseGrade::setGrade(float g)
{
    if (g >= 0.00 && g <= 100.00)
    {
        grade = g;
    }
    
}

int CourseGrade::getCourse() const
{
    return course;
}

float CourseGrade::getGrade() const
{
    return grade;
}

CourseGrade::CourseGrade(int c, float g)
{
    if (c >= 1000 && c <= 9999)
    {
        course = c;
    }
    else
    {
        course = 1000;
    }

    if (g >= 0.00 && g <= 100.00)
    {
        grade = g;
    }
    else
    {
        grade = 0.00;
    }
}
```

Can you guys please help me out? I have three objects due to the prompt, but it only asks for two pointers? I am completely unaware of how to get the maximumGrade to show the course with the largest grade. I have tried using if statements to compare the grades of the two pointers showing the values of the grades. It HAS to use pointers to compare the course grades. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have three objects due to the prompt, but it only asks for two pointers?

The only way to make sense of two pointers passed to `maximumGrade` is to assume that these are the beginning and end of an array which contains the three objects.

```
    CourseGrade courses[3] = { Course0, Course1, Course2 };
    cout << "The course with the maximum grade is: "
         << maximumGrade(courses, courses+3)->getCourse() << endl;
```

The body of `maximumGrade` can then be e. g.

```
    CourseGrade *c = NULL;
    float g = 0;    // current maximum
    for (; course0 < course1; ++course0) if (g <= course0->getGrade())
                                             g = (c = course0)->getGrade();
    return c;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had solved it forever ago.